# Variable in the ax.text not displaying (matplotlib)

Tags: matplotlib, variables, text

Any thought on why this solution is not working for me?

I am trying to add some text with variables with f'strings, with .format function and with this % but nothing works. Python says:
Input In [664]
ax1.text(x=0, y=-0.3, s)
^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

I've tried almost all solutions in the internet and cannot figute out where I am wrong.. Appreciate your help!!

P.S. This message workd fine in all formats when I print it. Not inside the plot as a text.

The most I could get is to get the text directly as it is with {} not variables

```
dfplot=df.copy()
# Plotting df

fig, [ax1, ax2, ax3] = plt.subplots(1,3,  figsize=(15, 5))

plt.style.use('fast')
# Temperature data
ax1.grid(visible=True, which='major', axis='both')
ax1.plot(d, t, color='red', alpha=0.7)
ax1.set_title('Temperature Forecast')
ax1.set_xticks(d)
ax1.set_xticklabels(d, rotation=90, fontsize=8)
ax1.fill_between(d, t, color='red', alpha=0.3)

# HERE IS WHERE IT GETS WRONG

s="Hello!\nNow is {city}.format() the temperature is {temp}. \nSunrise today is at {sunrisrtime}. \nSunset will be at {sunsettime}"

ax1.text(x=0, y=-0.3, s)
```

Comment: The specific error is because you need `s=s`: `ax1.text(x=0, y=-0.3, s=s)`

Comment: "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument" -> you're "naming" x, and y, but leaving `s` unnamed. that's the issue

Comment: Dear Paul and BigBen! Finally, i've figured the correct code for that: ```s= f'Currently in {city} the temperature is {temp}. \nSunrise today is at {sunrisrtime}. \nSunset will be at {sunsettime}'
ax1.text(x=-1.5, y=1.4, s=s, transform=ax.transAxes)```